# Android service not starting

Tags: android

I'm developing an app with a service (inherited from [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)). The service is started via the manifest:

```
<application ...>
  ...
  <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".NotificationService" />
</application>
```

This used to work. Now, suddenly (with no apparent change in the code), it stopped working. When I debug my app, **the service simply does not start**.

- Yes, the service is in the same package as the main activity.
- Yes, the `service` tag is inside the `application` tag.
- Yes, I have uninstalled my app to ensure I have a clean environment.
- Yes, I have rebooted my device several times.
- No, a `Debug.waitForDebugger()` in the service does not trigger.

I have cleaned the project. I have restarted Eclipse. Not sure what more I can try. Please help!

Comment: can you provide some relevant code from where you are starting service

Comment: Lol. You're on to something :P Please show me an answer with a call to `startService` :)

Comment: If you're starting the service from an Activity: `startService (new Intent (this, NotificationService.class));` But surely you had something like that till now?

Comment: `The service is started via the manifest` do you mean, the service is declared in the manifest, but as long as no one asks for it to start it won't start?

Comment: @l33t  : because it's very important how you are starting service. that's why i'm saying provide some reference code

Comment: I did start the service, but conditionally. It was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startService` was never called. Hence, an error in my code. My question does however pinpoint a couple of gotchas that may prove useful :)